# Can't SSH into Ubuntu server from any machine

Tags: ssh

I have an Ubuntu server running which was working fine till now. I can't SSH into the server and get the following error:

```
Connecting to user@10.10.0.6...
OpenSSH_7.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.10.0.6 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.0.6 [10.10.0.6] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: getpeername failed: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I also tried logging into another machine on the same network and ssh into Ubuntu server from that machine and it still does not work. Any ideas on what might be going on and how to resolve it?

Comment: I think you need to create your ssh keys on teh servier... I think it's sshkeygen

Comment: Thanks, I am away from the server, but I'll try it. It's funny how it stopped working all by itself. I have the exchanged the keys in the past but I never disabled password login.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to login to the server directly and generate your ssh keys:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

This will ask some questions so you can set up your key.

Do this on your client machine as well.

There is more info available [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/).

You may also need to reinstall openssh:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall openssh-server openssh-client
```